# Abel summation in function fields

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I’m wondering if there is an Abel summation (partial summation) analogue could in a function field setting. I have a strong feeling it does but I’m just not sure how the analogue would look.

Comment: Work...like in what? You could ask as well whether multiplication "works" in function fields... what do you mean **exactly** ?

Comment: Sorry rushed my phrasing!